# Converting dataframe to json

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i want to transform following dataframe

```
| id  | date         | score |
| --- | ------------ | ----- |
| 1   | 2021-01-01   | 1     |
| 1   | 2021-01-02   | 2     |
| 1   | 2021-01-03   | 3     |
```

into json of following format

`[{id: 1}, {date: 2021-01-01, score: 1}, {date: 2021-01-02, score: 2}, {date: 2021-01-03, score: 3}]`

I've tried using `to_json(orient='records')` but that would produce:

`[{id: 1, date: 2021-01-01, score: 1}, {id: 1, date: 2021-01-02, score: 2}, {id: 1, date: 2021-01-03, score: 3}]`

Is there some pre-processing to do before `to_json()` that will help get my output or should i manually create key value pairs ?

##### NOTE

There won't be more than one id.

Comment: What should happen if there are more than a single value for the id column?

Comment: there won't be more than single value

Answer (score 2):

There is a native `to_json()` method to the pandas `DataFrame`:
The orient parameter will help you out with the output format.

```
df.to_json(filepath, orient='records')
```

This should do it:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([{'id': 1, 'date': '2021-01-01', 'score': 1}, {'id': 1, 'date': '2021-01-02', 'score': 2}, {'id': 1, 'date': '2021-01-03', 'score': 3}])

import json
json.dumps([{'id': 1}] + df.drop(columns=['id']).to_dict(orient='records'))
```

if more than one id:

```
json.dumps([[{'id': int(k)}] + df[df['id'] == k].drop(columns=['id']).to_dict(orient='records') for k in df['id'].unique()])
```

Comment: sorry about that, but  that way its like you have a different dataframe on the first row of the json, so pandas wont't do it natively.  Just concatenate it using orient =records

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your wanting your data grouped by id but then you want a weird format on top of that which `.to_json` won't give you.

You haven't made it clear what you expect to occur when there are multiple indexes but my best guess of want you want is:

```
import json
import pandas as pd

def transform_group(group):
    index, dataframe = group
    output = dataframe[['date', 'score']].to_dict(orient='records')
    output.insert(0, {"id": index})
    return output

data = pd.DataFrame([
    {"id": 1, "date": "2021-01-01", "score": 1},
    {"id": 1, "date": "2021-01-02", "score": 2}, 
    {"id": 1, "date": "2021-01-03", "score": 3}
])
transformed_data = [transform_group(group) for group in data.groupby(data.id)]
print(json.dumps(transformed_data))
```